# Fsck does not work

Tags: fsck

Fsck isn’t doing its job here. When I try running it, I get a

> (No such file or directory) while executing `fsck.ext2` for `/dev/nve1n1p3`.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You haven't used the correct command. The spelling of the volume needs to be exact.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Thanks! This got resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the initramfs prompt, type:

```
fsck -f /dev/nvme1n1p3
```